# Ansible How do I compare the ansible two directories,Local directory

Tags: ansible

- I have the following directories

```sh
[root@pp-private-cloud test]# ls /tmp/test1/
11.txt  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt
```

Playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: test_copy_folder
    copy:
      src: /tmp/test1
      dest: /tmp/data
```

```
[root@pp-private-cloud test]# ansible-playbook site-test.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test_copy_folder] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- Delete `9.txt`，remote dir no diff,How to ensure the consistency of two directories

```sh
[root@pp-private-cloud test]# rm -rf /tmp/test1/9.txt

[root@pp-private-cloud test]# ansible-playbook site-test.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test_copy_folder] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Change action Copy to implement multiple file differences comparison

###### step 1

```py
diff --git a/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py b/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py
index ef14dd3798..0f245cffec 100644
--- a/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py
+++ b/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-# (c) 2012-2014, Michael DeHaan <michael.dehaan@gmail.com>
+# # (c) 2012-2014, Michael DeHaan <michael.dehaan@gmail.com>
 # (c) 2017 Toshio Kuratomi <tkuraotmi@ansible.com>
 #
 # This file is part of Ansible
@@ -504,6 +504,8 @@ class ActionModule(ActionBase):
         dest = self._remote_expand_user(dest)
 
         implicit_directories = set()
+
+        module_return['diff'] = []
         for source_full, source_rel in source_files['files']:
             # copy files over.  This happens first as directories that have
             # a file do not need to be created later
@@ -514,7 +516,9 @@ class ActionModule(ActionBase):
             else:
                 follow = boolean(self._task.args.get('follow', False), strict=False)
 
-            module_return = self._copy_file(source_full, source_rel, content, content_tempfile, dest, task_vars, follow)
+            module_return_list = self._copy_file(source_full, source_rel, content, content_tempfile, dest, task_vars, follow)
+            module_return['diff'].append(module_return_list)
+
             if module_return is None:
                 continue
 
@@ -530,7 +534,18 @@ class ActionModule(ActionBase):
             if 'diff' in result and not result['diff']:
                 del result['diff']
             module_executed = True
-            changed = changed or module_return.get('changed', False)
+            # changed = changed or module_return.get('changed', False)
+        # Hack Copy diff
+        changed_list = []
+        for diff_dict in module_return['diff']:
+            if diff_dict.get('changed', False):
+                changed_list.append('True')
+            else:
+                changed_list.append('False')
+        if 'True' in changed_list:
+            changed = True
+        else:
+            changed = False
 
         for src, dest_path in source_files['directories']:
             # Find directories that are leaves as they might not have been
@@ -584,7 +599,12 @@ class ActionModule(ActionBase):
             if 'path' in result and 'dest' not in result:
                 result['dest'] = result['path']
         else:
-            result.update(dict(dest=dest, src=source, changed=changed))
+            # result.update(dict(dest=dest, src=source, changed=changed))
+            result = module_return
+            result['src'] = source
+            result['dest'] = dest
+            result['msg'] = 'Recursive File Diff'
+            result['changed'] = changed
 
         # Delete tmp path
         self._remove_tmp_path(self._connection._shell.tmpdir)
```

###### step 2 Modify the standard output callback

```py
diff --git a/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py b/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
index 111814f0c9..ba4351f97d 100644
--- a/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
+++ b/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
@@ -74,5 +74,8 @@ class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
         self._display.display("%s | UNREACHABLE! => %s" % (result._host.get_name(), self._dump_results(result._result, indent=4)), color=C.COLOR_UNREACHABLE)
 
     def v2_on_file_diff(self, result):
+        if isinstance(result._result['diff'], list):
+            for i in result._result['diff']:
+                self._display.display(self._get_diff(i['diff']))
         if 'diff' in result._result and result._result['diff']:
             self._display.display(self._get_diff(result._result['diff']))
```

###### result

```yaml
~/workspace/ansible(add-mocopy) » ansible localhost  -m copy  -a 'src=/tmp/test1/  dest=/tmp/test2/'   -C  -D                                    yayun@zyymac
/Users/yayun/workspace/ansible/lib/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

--- before
+++ after: /tmp/test1/requirements.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,10 @@
+# Note: this requirements.txt file is used to specify what dependencies are
+# needed to make the package run rather than for deployment of a tested set of
+# packages.  Thus, this should be the loosest set possible (only required
+# packages, not optional ones, and with the widest range of versions that could
+# be suitable)
+jinja2
+PyYAML
+paramiko
+cryptography
+setuptools

--- before
+++ after: /tmp/test1/t1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+1 add content
+t1 frist

--- before
+++ after: /tmp/test1/t2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+t2 add
+t2 second


localhost | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "dest": "/tmp/test2/", 
    "msg": "Recursive File Diff", 
    "src": "/tmp/test1/"
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This should be part of the standard code.

Answer (score 0):

The [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/synchronize_module.html) module is better suited for your requirement. Just like `rsync` takes `--delete` option, we can enable it in the task to delete any files on destination that don't exist on source.

Example:

```yaml
  - name: test_copy_folder
    synchronize:
      src: /tmp/test1
      dest: /tmp/data
      delete: true
```

**Note**: You may need to add `recursive: true`, but it worked for me without setting it.

Comment: synchronize module ,No git style comparisons,